# What is the maximum size of SQLite or Core Data database on iOS?

Tags: ios, sqlite, core-data

What is the maximum size of SQLite or Core Data database on iOS, how many rows can be added to a sqlite/Core Data database on iOS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The max size of your SQLite database is only limited by free disk space.

The number of rows in one SQLite database is defined by the `ROWID` type that is a signed 64 bit value. In a worst case scenario where one managed object needs say 100 rows in the database to specify all many-to-many relations there would still be no limit except available disk space.

Short answer to both: only limited by free disk space on the users device.