# What is the maximum size of single file in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios

I have searched some posts and cannot find what the maximum filesize is under iPhone.

- [max size of an iOS application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4753100/max-size-of-an-ios-application)
- [maximum size of sqlite or database on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5953856/what-is-the-maximum-size-of-sqlite-or-core-data-database-on-ios)

As the above posts said, the maximum filesize depends on the free disk space. So, can I store everything into sqlite file and it's filesize can exceed 4GB or 10GB ?

Comment: Not sure about the correct answer But, the largest app on my phone is Spotify, with 3.6GB.  I believe, its the available disk space that decides the max size of the file .

Comment: iOS is internally 32 bit OS system. At max it can distinguish memory address of size power(2,32) - 1 , which is 4 GB. So you should be fine with that much size at max theoretically.

Comment: @Apurv That has nothing to do with the hard disk.  That will only be relevant if the OP tries to load the entire database into memory, at which point it would be killed long before it reached 4 GB (seeing how the max allowed memory use on the newest device, iPad 3, is 650 MB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the following links I found,

1. [Mac OS, HFS File System volumn and file limits](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2422)
2. [iOS filesystem, HFSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805623/ios-filesystem-hfs)
3. [HFS, Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus)

As the first link says, "The theoretical maximum file size for a Mac OS Extended file system is millions of terabytes. In practice, **the maximum file size is equivalent to the maximum volume size**, except for a small amount of disk space reserved for file system information."

Because the maximum filesize is equal to the maximum volumn size, and consider the factor about the free disk space.

So, in my conclusion, the maximum size of single file depends on the free disk space.