# How can I find maximum available space in SQLite DB for a hybrid app?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, hybrid-mobile-app

I am developing a Hybrid app (ionic 1) using Cordova. The app is an extension of a web app. I wish to make an offline mode in the app which will allow the user to do limited functions, however, this still requires some data to reside on the app in SQLite Database.
Since the database on the web app is large, I wish to see how I can

- get maximum available space in the SQLite Database
- throw an alert to the user when the space is limited

Shall appreciate if someone can help?

Answer (score 2):

If you use a native SQLite DB (e.g. via [cordova-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) plugin), then the size is virtually unlimited i.e. only limited by available device storage space.

References for [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31260539/777265) and [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5954558/777265).